# Property without class in RDF

Tags: rdf, rdfs, rdfa, rdfstore, rdfs+

I have a class `Person`. It has two properties `hasAge` and `hasZipCode`.

```
:Person :hasAge     <literal>
        :hasZipCode <literal>
```

I would like to say that `hasAge` and `hasZipCode` are sub-properties of `hasColumn` property.  Hence I mentioned it like following.

```
:hasAge       rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn
:hasZipCode   rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn
```

However, in my RDF graph, I don't have any class that contains property `hasColumn`. I mean I don't have something like following:

```
:Table :hasColumn <literal>
```

Is it allowed in RDF to define a property (e.g., `hasColumn`) without a class?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class ChicagoPerson. It has two properties hasAge and
>   hasZipCode, and their values are mentioned below.
>
> ```
> :ChicagoPerson :hasAge     "30"
>                :hasZipCode "60543"
> ```

This doesn't make sense.  In this snippet, ChicagoPerson is an *individual* (or resource), and has values for the two properties that you mention.

> I would like to say that hasAge and hasZipCode are sub-properties of
>   hasColumn property. Hence I mentioned it like following.
>
> ```
> :hasAge       rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn
> :hasZipCode   rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn
> ```

This is the correct way to do this.  This means that if you have RDFS inference available, then you'll have the data:

```
:ChicagoPerson :hasAge     "30" ,
               :hasZipCode "60543" ,
               :hasColumn "30", "60543" .
```

> However, in my RDF graph, I don't have any class that contains
>   property hasColumn. I mean I don't have something like following:
>
> ```
> :Table :hasColumn <literal>
> ```

Again, I think you're confusing the idea of classes and individuals.  A class is a collection of individuals.  If you have RDFS inference available, then the subproperty axioms you wrote above will allow that RDFS reasoner to infer the additional triples that I mentioned.  The extra triples that you'll see are

```
:ChicagoPerson :hasColumn "30", "60543" .
```

not something with Table as the subject.

> Is it allowed in RDF to define a property (e.g., hasColumn) without a
>   class?

RDF doesn't really have any notion of defining properties.  RDF just has triples of the form **subject, predicate, object**.  Schema languages like RDFS and OWL assign special meaning to certain kinds of triples, usually by assigning a meaning to particular predicates.  E.g., in RDFS and OWL, the predicate **rdfs:subPropertyOf** gets a special meaning.

Do you actually have an RDFS reasoner running on your dataset?

Comment: Joshua Taylor: I have edited my question. Now instead of individual, I am showing class level information. It is a cook-up example, and I am not running any reasoner. In short, my question was in RDF can we say a property is a subPropertyOf another property without assigning that property to any class. I think your answer is yes. Correct me If I am wrong. What reasoner can I use? Is there any reasoner in Virtuoso?

Comment: @S.M.ShamimulHasan RDF doesn't have any notion of "assigning a property to a class".  Properties don't belong to classes.  You can declare domains and ranges of properties, but they don't belong to classes.  An individual/resource x can have a value for a property p, which just means that there's a triple (x,p,something) in the data.  You can make a property p a subproperty of property q just by adding the triple (p, subPropertyOf, q).  Nothing else is required.

Comment: @S.M.ShamimulHasan I don't see how the edit helps.  Renaming ChicagoPerson to Person doesn't make "I have a class Person. It has two properties hasAge and hasZipCode. :Person :hasAge     <literal>" any more sensible.  If Person is a class, and it's the domain of those properties, you'd have `hasAge rdfs:domain Person` to state that, and then you'd use it as `person72 rdf:type person ; hasAge 23 .`

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to define range of `:hasAge` as well? Like `:hasAge rdfs:range xsd:int`. Let's say `:hasAge rdfs:range xsd:int` and  `:hasZipcode rdfs:range xsd:string`. Now `:hasAge  rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn` and `:hasZipCode   rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasColumn`. Suppose `:hasColumn rdfs:domain :AllColumn` then what will be the range of `hasColumn`?

Comment: You don't *need* to define any ranges or domains. Ranges and domains are generally "intersections", but that's been described plenty of times in other places.  A property can have multiples domains (or ranges).  If a property P has domain C, then it means from a triple (x, P, _), we can infer that (x, rdf:type, C).  That's **all** it means.  So if P has multiple domains, say, C and D, then from (x, P, _), you can infer (x,rdf:type,C) *and* (x, rdf:type, D).

Comment: Many thanks. Please let me know about some reasoners that you mentioned earlier. Anything in Virtuoso will be useful. I also would like to purify my RDF concepts. Could please suggest me any book or reading materials with simple examples? I know about some RDF literature. However, I am looking for your suggestion.